# Handling windows messages from a subclass

Tags: c++, winapi

I have custom window encapsulated in a class with a static WndProc function to handle messages generated by it. Now I have a child class which implements some of the features in message handling proc differently then the parent class.

For example in the code below, what happens in WM_LBUTTONDOWN in the child class is different then what happens in the parent class.

I thought about polymorphism, but I think it won't work since the ::SetWindowLongPtr() is called from the parent class and "this" pointer passed to belongs to the parent class, correct me if I am wrong.

And if I am wrong and polymorphism will work in this case then too there are some messages which are not handled by the parent class and should be handled in the child class and putting an empty virtual function in the parent class just for that doesn't seems clean, beside its hard to put an empty virtual function for each and every message that window produce just for the sake of if in future it will be used.

There going to be several such child classes each one of them behaving differently for some messages but not all.

So, how should I go about doing it.

**parent.cpp**

```
parent::parent()
{

    WNDCLASSEX wincl;

    wincl.hInstance         = hInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName     = "parent";
    wincl.lpfnWndProc       = WndProc;
    wincl.style             = CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW;
    wincl.cbSize            = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    wincl.hIcon             = 0;
    wincl.hIconSm           = 0;
    wincl.hCursor           = ::LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName      = NULL;
    wincl.cbClsExtra        = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra        = 4;
    wincl.hbrBackground     = ::CreateSolidBrush( backgroundColor );

    ::RegisterClassEx ( &wincl );

    hwnd = ::CreateWindowEx ( 0, "parent", txt.c_str(), WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD, x, y, width, height, parent, 0, hInstance, 0 ) ;

    ::SetWindowLongPtr( hwnd , GWLP_USERDATA , ( LONG ) this ) ;

}



LRESULT CALLBACK parent::WndProc ( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{


   view::parent* panel = reinterpret_cast < view::parent* > (  ::GetWindowLongPtr ( hwnd , GWLP_USERDATA )  );


   switch (message)
   {    


      case WM_CREATE:

          ::SendMessage ( hwnd, WM_SETFONT, ( WPARAM ) panel->hFont, ( LPARAM ) true );

          break ;



      case WM_COMMAND:


          return panel->command ( message, wParam, lParam );

          break ;



      case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:


          return panel->lButton ( message, wParam, lParam );

          break;



      case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:


          return panel->rButton ( message, wParam, lParam );

          break;



      case WM_ERASEBKGND:


          return 1;

          break;



      case WM_PAINT:


          return panel->paint ( );


          break ;



      default:


         return ::DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);


   }

    return 0 ;


};
```

Thanks.

Comment: A common way to do this is to create virtual or pure virtual member functions, e.g. `virtual LRESULT onButtonDown(...) {}` etc.

Comment: @JoshGreifer so are you saying Polymorphism will work in this case, even if the "this" pointer passed to ::SetWindowLongPtr() belongs to the parent class ?

Comment: Make `parent::WndProc` virtual. Derived classes override `child::WndProc`, handle the messages they want to override, and for those they don't want to override, forward the call to `parent::WndProc`. [This is a standard technique](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx).

Comment: @StudentX: yes, polymorphism will work just fine. Calling derived class functionality via base class pointers is what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: @StudentX: your WndProc needs to check if `panel` is NULL before using it. `WM_CREATE` is not the first message a window receives, and the window receives messages before `CreateWindowEx()` exits, before your code calls `SetWindowLongPtr()`. A slightly safer approach is to pass the `this` pointer to `CreateWindowEx()` and then call `SetWindowLongPtr()` in the `WM_CREATE` handler. You still have to account for messages being received before `WM_CREATE`, though.

Comment: When in doubt about how something works (in this case virtual dispatch and the `this` pointer), you should write a simple test program, inspect its execution and learn how it works.  Don't keep guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class parent
{
private:
    // ...
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
protected:
    HWND m_hwnd;
    // ...
    virtual LRESULT WndProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual LRESULT DefWndProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual LRESULT command(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual LRESULT lButtonDown(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual LRESULT rButtonDown(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual LRESULT paint();
    // ...
public:
    parent();
    virtual ~parent();
    // ...
};
```

```
parent::parent()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wincl = {0};

    wincl.hInstance         = hInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName     = "parent";
    wincl.lpfnWndProc       = WndProcCallback;
    wincl.style             = CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW;
    wincl.cbSize            = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wincl.hIcon             = 0;
    wincl.hIconSm           = 0;
    wincl.hCursor           = ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName      = NULL;
    wincl.cbClsExtra        = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra        = 4;
    wincl.hbrBackground     = ::CreateSolidBrush(backgroundColor);

    ::RegisterClassEx(&wincl);

    m_hwnd = NULL;
    ::CreateWindowEx(0, "parent", txt.c_str(), WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD, x, y, width, height, parent, 0, hInstance, this);
}

parent::~parent()
{
    if (m_hwnd)
        DestroyWindow(m_hwnd);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK parent::WndProcCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    parent* panel;

    if (message == WM_CREATE)
    {
        CREATESTRUCT *cs = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam);
        panel = static_cast<parent*>(cs->lpCreateParams);
        panel->m_hwnd = hwnd;
        ::SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(panel));
    }
    else
       panel = reinterpret_cast<parent*>(::GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

    if (panel)
        return panel->WndProc(message, wParam, lParam);

    return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT parent::WndProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch (message)
   {    
      case WM_CREATE:
          ::SendMessage(m_hwnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) hFont, TRUE);
          break ;

      case WM_COMMAND:
          return command(wParam, lParam);
          break ;

      case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
          return lButtonDown(wParam, lParam);
          break;

      case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
          return rButtonDown(wParam, lParam);
          break;

      case WM_ERASEBKGND:
          return 1;
          break;

      case WM_PAINT:
          return paint();
          break;
    }

    return DefWndProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT parent::DefWndProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return ::DefWindowProc(m_hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT parent::command(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWndProc(WM_COMMAND, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT parent::lButtonDown(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWndProc(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT parent::rButtonDown(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWndProc(WM_RBUTTONDOWN, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT parent::paint()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Not only does this embrace polymorphism and encapsulation, but making `WndProc()` itself virtual allows derived classes to override behavior for any received message (well, any message received after `WM_CREATE` that is), especially messages the `parent` has no concept of:

```
class child : public parent
{
protected:
    LRESULT WndProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
```

```
LRESULT child::WndProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_SOMETHING)
    {
        // ...
        return 0;
    }

    return parent::WndProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have already figured that out and even changed how the "this" pointer was passed to the callback to exactly like you did with a minor modification :P. I have a question though, if I am using CREATESTRUCT to retrieve the pointer to the object in WM_CREATE like in you example, then it doesn't work, so I changed WM_CREATE to WM_NCCREATE like in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx and it work, even the MSDN uses WM_CREATE then why it isn't working for me ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381400%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Define "doesn't work" exactly. Both `WM_CREATE` and `WM_NCCREATE` work fine for me, the `parent*` pointer is valid in the `CREATESTRUCT` structure in both messages. However, one change I had to make was moving the assignment of the `parent::m_hwnd` member so it is available inside of `parent::WndProc()` while `CreateWindowEx()` is still running. I have updated my answer accordingly.